# Fortran calls C++ pointer function

Tags: c++, pointers, fortran

I have a problem with connecting Fortran program with C++ function.
My task is to call C++ function pointer from fortran, example:

```
// C++ function pointer
double* GetSplinePtr()
{
    return sp;
}
```

I use ***iso_c_binding*** procedure and fortran ***interface***.
For non-pointer function i usually use this declaration:

```
real(kind=c_double) function Name(x,y) bind(c, name='Name')
use iso_c_binding
implicit none
real(c_double), intent(in), value :: x,y
end function Name
```

But what should I use for function which returns a pointer?

Thanks!

Comment: What about the type `C_PTR`, also a component of the module `iso_c_binding`?

Comment: Are you sure `intent(in)` and `value` are allowed at the same time?

Comment: @vladimirf `intent(inout)` and `intent(out)` certainly conflict with `value`, but not `intent(in)`?

Comment: Yeas, I remembered the constraint wrong, it is (F2008): `C558
 An entity with the VALUE attribute shall not have the ALLOCATABLE, INTENT (INOUT), INTENT
(OUT), POINTER, or VOLATILE attributes.`

Comment: Is it a C or C++ pointer?  If it is a C++ pointer, there is name mangling.  It should be declared as **extern "C"** on the C++ side to avoid the name   mangling.

Answer (score 3):

As Ross comments, you must make the Fortran interface to return the C pointer and do the conversion to a Fortran pointer yourself.

```
interface
  function GetSplinePtr() result(res) bind(C, name="GetSplinePtr")
    use iso_c_binding
    type(C_ptr) :: res
  end function
end interface
```

In the calling code you have to call `c_f_pointer()` from the `iso_c_binding` module:

```
  use iso_c_binding

  type(c_ptr) :: p
  real(c_double), pointer :: x

  p = GetSplinePtr()

  call c_f_pointer(p, x)
```